# As a user who is new to the review process, is there a best-practice guide for reviewing first-posts/late-answers?

Tags: support, review-queue

I've read [How should I review First Posts on topics I am completely unfamiliar with?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2838/how-should-i-review-first-posts-on-topics-i-am-completely-unfamiliar-with), but my question relates to the following line in the available guidance:

***Edit*** to improve the answer's appearance, clarity, or accuracy

Is there a list of basics that should be considered when reviewing a question/answer? For example:

**For questions:**

- Is the title clear?
- Does it have relevant tags?
- Is it on-topic?
- Is the SPaG (spelling, punctuation and grammar) correct?

**For answers:**

- Does it actually answer the question?
- Does it reference any sources referred to?
- Does it repeat information in another answer already posted?

---

I'd like to ensure that if I review any questions, that I'm consistent with the approach taken by experienced users.

Comment: The fact that you've given it this much thought indicates that you've given it more thought than about 95% of reviewers.

Comment: Personally, the best advice I can offer to a newer user wanting to improve their editing skills is to use the [edit history](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/10604/revisions) tab on questions to see what changes have been made by more experienced editors. There are [14 users who've made more than a thousand edits](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all). Reviewing their recent edits should give you a very solid understanding of the sorts of changes that should be made. Often it's not a case of following set procedures but more a case of "*doing what feels right*"

Comment: @Valorum Thanks, that's helpful. I'll spy on some edits for a while until I get an idea of who-does-what. In my head I'm usually thinking *SPaG, Tag or Flag?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, thank you for taking the time to post this! It's rare to see such a conscientious reviewer, and much appreciated. I hope you'll be more active in the review queues in the future!

---

There's a fairly small set of possible actions you can take on a First Post or Late Answer: you can **upvote**, **downvote**, (suggest an) **edit**, add a **comment**, **flag**, (vote to) **close**, (vote to) **delete**, or **upvote a comment**. Or of course just click **No Action Needed** or **Skip**.

Here's a rough checklist, off the top of my head, of what to consider when reviewing these posts:

- **Is the post good?** Is it an interesting question, or a useful answer? If so, **upvote**.
- **Is it so bad that it shouldn't stay?** Is it spam, abusive, or nonsense? Is it an off-topic question, a duplicate, or otherwise worthy of closure (excessively broad, unclear, or opinion-based)? Is it posted as an answer without attempting to answer the question, or incomprehensible? If so, **flag**. (I see you have less than 3k rep; higher-rep users might vote to **close** or **delete** in this case.)
- **Is it bad but not *that* bad?** Is it a useless or poorly researched (but still on-topic) question, or an incorrect or poorly written answer (but still a comprehensible answer)? If so, **downvote**.
- **Can you improve it?** Does it have any typos or spelling/grammar mistakes, or is it poorly formatted in some way that you know how to fix? If so, **(suggest an) edit**.
- **Do you have any feedback for the user?** Some new users take well to any feedback, either using it to improve their post or just letting it make them feel at home. Even if the post is from a drive-by unregistered user who's unlikely ever to return, a little helpful commentary feedback can still be useful for anyone *else* reading it in the future. If you have anything useful to say, **leave a comment**. If someone else has said it already, you might consider **upvoting their comment**.

**If you don't know** the answers to some of the above queries (e.g. because the post is about a sci-fi or fantasy work you've never read/seen and know nothing about), then click **Skip**. This means your review count isn't incremented and the post stays in the queue to be reviewed by someone else, hopefully someone more knowledgeable about the topic.

**If there's really nothing to be done** on the post - it's neither good enough to be worth upvoting, nor bad enough to be worth downvoting or editing, nor interesting enough to be worth commenting on - you can click **No Action Needed**. But at this point I'll quote a moderator from another site, in [a post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3096/5373) from which I personally learned a lot of what I know about reviewing:

> The one thing that causes new users to leave most often is a lack of human interaction. Don't let new users ask or answer into the void. <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> is almost always flat-out wrong. You are the only one to review a user's first post; bear this in mind when reviewing.

Comment: +1 to mentioning the "skip" button. Too few users seem willing to admit that sometimes they simply aren't equipped to deal with a question.

Comment: @Valorum Yep. Some people are more interested in getting Reviewer/Steward badges than actually reviewing well. Hence suggestions like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270418/278659) arising.

Comment: Disappointingly, no-one mentioned [Skippy the Jedi Droid](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skippy_the_Jedi_Droid), presumably for fear of looking like they're endorsing [robo-reviewing](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5144/what-is-robo-reviewing/5145) :-).

Comment: Thanks @Randal'Thor, that's all really useful. I've given reviewing a shot in the past, and I'll certainly try to be more active!