# What is a review in Science Fiction and Fantasy?

Tags: support, review-queue

What is writing a review on SFF:SE? I'm not sure why, but there's a new icon in the top , along with the inbox, reputation, help, and "other sites" icon. It has "queues" for reviews and other things. What are these reviews for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161390/278659) on Main Meta (the Stack Exchange network-wide meta site). The review queues work pretty much the same on Science Fiction & Fantasy as on any other site:

- With at least [500 rep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), you can **review new users' posts** to see if any action is required on them (voting, flagging, editing, commenting, etc.) See [As a user who is new to the review process, is there a best-practice guide for reviewing first-posts/late-answers?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10604/31394) for advice on reviewing in these queues.
- With at least [2000 rep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit), you can **review suggested edits from low-rep users** and also **review flagged low-quality posts for potential deletion**.
- With at least [3000 rep](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you can take part in **closing inappropriate or off-topic questions** and also **reopening closed questions** that were closed wrongly or have been edited and improved.

Note that you're not *obligated* to take part in any of these activities: they are privileges, not responsibilities.